# All Nested Attributes in rails form save with the value of the first one

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with updating a nested attribute for an `invoice` using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on my rails project:

When I select the quantity for each item they all save the same as the value for the first item, for example:

In the form for the invoice I have 3 different items with 3 different quantities for each of them. Independently of what value I select for each of them, the records are always saved with the value of the first item.

Here is the Controller:

```
def edit
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @printers = Printer.cheap_first
  (9-@invoice.invoice_items.size).times do
  @invoice.invoice_items.build
  end
end

def update
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  if @invoice.update(invoice_params) 
      flash[:notice] = "Invoice updated succesfully."
      redirect_to(:action =>'show')
  else
    render('edit')
  end
end

private
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:client, :salesman, :discount, :organization, :address, :zp, :currency, :rate, invoice_items_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :printer_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Here is the Model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :printers, :through => :invoice_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items, reject_if: proc {|attributes| attributes['printer_id'].blank?}, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is the View:

```
<% z = 0 %>
<%= f.fields_for :invoice_items, remote: true do |ff| %>
<div id=<%="invoice_item_#{z}"%> class="hidden" >
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h3><%="Printer #{z+1}"%></h3>
    <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
        <%= ff.label(:printer_id, "Printer:") %>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-cube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <%= ff.select(:printer_id, @printers.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, {:include_blank => 'Select a printer'},{:class => 'form-control'}) %>
        </div>              
        <%= ff.label(:quantity, "Quantity:") %>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <%= ff.select(:quantity, options_for_select(1..10),{}, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Number'}) %>
        </div>          
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% z = z+1 %>
    <% end %>
```

What is wrong with the code or what am I missing to achieve the change in `:quantity` that I need when updating an invoice?

Comment: can you show us the params that get sent up when you go to submit the update? i trust the create route (which isnt displayed) works just fine?

Comment: @PhilVarg I found that the records are always saved with the quantity value of the first item, while creating and updating. Already updated to show the actual issue.

Comment: can you edit in the parameters that are getting sent up? they should be visible from the rails console during the request

Comment: i'd also be interested in seeing some of the generated html. i'm wondering if, because youre not specifying which invoice_item, the name of the quantity input field is not being incremented, and thus, all the same, which might cause the sent up parameters to be identical to the first entry.

Comment: Thank you @PhilVarg , I narrowed it down to a failure in my view, the records where being saved correctly.